# Exposed wiring repair?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am installing new ceiling fans and noticed this red wire had some exposed copper. Can I just wrap it with a cable cable repair/electrical sealant pad or do I need to have the entire wiring replaced? See image below.

[image: wire]

Comment: This is in North America I take it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see some exposed copper on the white wire if this is what you are talking about I would suggest shrink tubing, it can be shrunk with a match as most don’t have heat guns, the better types have an adhesive sealant that holds and seals much better than electrical tape, tape tends to slide off and move around more than electrical tape but inside a box a proper tape job with 50% overlap would protect the exposed copper from being hazardous.

50% over lap is starting the wrap at least an inch prior to the damage after the first wrap the over lap of 50% creates 2 thicknesses of tape , for added thickness a second pass provides 4 thickness.

I would recommend a quality shrink tubing over tape.

Comment: What about liquid tape (?), like I've seen in some of the big box stores?

Comment: Use a white shrink tube so it's not mistaken for a white marked black hot.+

Comment: shrink the tubing with a butane lighter ... using a match causes black soot on the tubing

Comment: I even use a propane / mapp gas torch on the big stuff if you move quickly it doesn’t turn black . A lighter on the small stuff is all I have used for 20+ years just don’t try to shrink it all the way down but move the lighter around so it doesn’t over heat.

Comment: The exposed copper wire should be checked for reduced cross section. A hairdryer can pose as a temporary hot air gun if the air inlet is reduced by ca. 70 to 90%. The hairdryer can be hold accordingly by 1 hand at the air inlet.

Comment: I agree that shrink tube is the better fix because it's easier.  A hair dryer will shrink a little piece of shrink tubing like this easily.

Answer (score 1):

Yo sugiero que coloque la cinta aislante en el cable blanco darle al menos tres vueltas, después juntar los tres cables y de igual manera ponerles cinta aislante  a los tres juntos esto evitará que se desfacé del l otro y puedan probócar algún corto circuito

**Google Translate:**

I suggest that you put the insulating tape on the white wire to give it at least three turns, then put the three wires together and in the same way put insulating tape to the three together. This will prevent you from getting out of touch with the other where they could try to short circuit.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We're an English-only stack, although there are other stacks in other languages. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.